# Jsf 2.0 dynamically remove component from view

Tags: java, jsf-2

I am trying to replace a component in the view using the PreRenderViewEvent but it doesn't work. The replaced component still renders.

Here is the code I'm using

```
    CommandButton toRender = ( CommandButton ) ctx.getApplication().
            createComponent(
            "org.primefaces.component.CommandButton" );
    toRender.setAjax( false );
    toRender.setLabel( "View" );
    toRender.getAttributes().put( "TargetState", State.table );
    toRender.setValue( State.table );
    if ( getToRender() != null )
    {
        getChildren().remove( getToRender() );
        getToRender().setParent( null );
    }
    getChildren().add( toRender );
    setToRender( toRender );
```

and here is the getter and setter for the current component

```
public UIComponent getToRender()
{
    return ( UIComponent ) getStateHelper().eval( PropertyKeys.toRender,
            null );
}

public void setToRender( UIComponent toRender )
{
    getStateHelper().put( PropertyKeys.toRender, toRender );
    handleAttribute( "toRender", toRender );
}
```

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Comment: With >200 reputation and >50 questions you should know how to use the editor properly. Read the formatting rules and pay attention to the preview area below the editor.

Comment: Sorry BalusC, I'm sure it was oversight. Thanks for the pointer